# Do we have a word "Soft Ice" in English

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I am living in Denmark and there is a kind of ice-cream that they call "Soft Ice". Do we have the same world in English or is it just "Soft serve"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89642/discussion-on-question-by-ashkan-sirous-do-we-have-a-word-soft-ice-in-english).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling Denmark "soft ice" looks like exactly what Americans would call "**soft serve**" or soft serve ice cream. There is an ice-cream adjacent treat made of literal soft ice (at least in New York) that we call *shaved ice* or *Italian ice*. It's somewhat similar to [granita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granita).

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what you get when you order 'Soft Ice' in Denmark, it's hard to say what the equivalent in English is. But I can tell you that in the U.S.A. we don't use the term 'Soft Ice'.

Soft-serve ice cream comes out of a machine straight into a dish or cone, and has the consistency of mashed potatoes.

@user3169 is correct that we wouldn't call ice cream 'ice'.